# No Callback after SQLite-Request

Tags: fullcalendar

awesome plugin.
But I tried to load some events via SQL-Rquest.
The Request is successfully, I can put the Array in another Container or alert them, but the Calendar wouldnt load the events. Here my Script

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
            {
             header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
             editable: true,        
             events: function(start, end, callback)
                        {
                        var rs = db.execute("select * from xCal");
                        var i = 0;
                        var events = '[';
                        while(rs.isValidRow()) 
                            {                       
                            if(i == 0){var events=events}else{events = events+','}
                            events=events+
                                        "{id:'"+rs.fieldByName('id')+"',"+
                                        "title:'"+rs.fieldByName('title')+"',"+
                                        "allDay:'"+rs.fieldByName('allDay')+"',"+
                                        "start:'"+rs.fieldByName('start')+"',"+
                                        "end:'"+rs.fieldByName('end')+"',"+
                                        "url:'"+rs.fieldByName('url')+"',"+
                                        "description:'"+rs.fieldByName('description')+"'}";
                            i++;
                            rs.next(); 
                            }
                        events = events+']';
                        callback( events );

                        }

            });
```

Udate cause comments .....

Thanks for replaying, but thats not the reason. I changed the code (removed quotes and the url complete), but it´s not running :( .

If I try to put the return of SQL request in the event-option, its runnig perfect. It seems, I have a problem with the callback();.

I have alerted the callback-var.

```
function(events){
            callback(events);
            popLoading();
            }
```

Calls callback itself?

Update cause answer ....

See above. Believe me, the string is correct. BTW I´m using Unix timestamp ;)

Comment: could you possibly write an exact dump of the feed to text. Allday for example should not have quotes! and url might have illegal cahracter that need escapin.. its a bit of a pian but once it goes this plugin rocks.

Answer (score 0):

So if you use

```
 events: function(start, end, callback) { }
```

to make your events you have to create a jscript array .. not a json type string.

So as a basic and simple example that works.

```
events:function(start,end,callback)
        {
            var event = [];
            event.push({
                title: 'Garten',
                start: '2011-05-10T00:00:00',
                allday: true
            });

            callback(event);
        }
```

On it works as this example shows

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/6wE8v/

You just need to plug your db stuff in. Apologies for the confusion in the comments

so a bit of your code:

```
id: rs.fieldByName('id'),
title: rs.fieldByName('title'),
start: rs.fieldByName('start'),
etc..
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn´t helps, the String is okay, see above

Comment: OK write out EXACTLY what  "start:'"+rs.fieldByName('start')+"',"+
                                        "end:'"+rs.fieldByName('end')+"',"+  is? The actaul real text in there with any ' , " or whatever.

Comment: Compare to this   "start":"2011-05-03T00:00:00","end":"2011-05-03T00:00:00"

Comment: i think your event building strings are incorrect. and the calendar cannot successfully parse your values.. debug debug debug..

Comment: Okay, thanks at first, but I tried the String in my version and in Your version. There is no Change, sorry. I tried also to add events from a variable, doesn´t work :(

Comment: The current string looks like [{"id":"1","title":"Garten","allDay":false,"start":"1303965000","end":"1304016120"}]

Comment: looks ok..  well have a tinker here- i set up a fiddle for you- lets see what happens - this is a working example - plug your code in save it and lets see what happens- i wil try too  http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/6wE8v/

Comment: okay, i tried it in the fiddle, same result ... I can´t add events from a variable

Comment: there must be some foramtting error- did you save your version- i can look at it quick

Comment: ok i figured it out- it works now- it was my mistake a bit i never used fucntion to make events only ajax and json. http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/6wE8v/