# How do I get the actual date the user clicked on with Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When a user clicks on an event, I am looking for a way to obtain the date that the user clicked on. `eventClick()` only returns the start date of the event, and `dayClick()` of course, does not fire since the user clicked on an event.

Or, I'm looking for a way for `dayClick()` to fire regardless if the user clicks on an empty calendar cell or on an event.

Comment: that is a good question. Will try and look into that - no answer off the top of my head now.

Comment: I'm looking for something like this. I need the time a user clicked, that you're given in dayClick, but when the user has clicked an event. Now we're only given the start of the event. Had any luck with this?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread but it might help someone (works only on the month view)

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    // Get the case number in the row
    // pos X clicked on the row / total width of the row * 100 (to percent) / (percent of 7 days by week)
    var caseNumber = Math.floor((Math.abs(jsEvent.offsetX + jsEvent.currentTarget.offsetLeft) / $(this).parent().parent().width() * 100) / (100 / 7));
    // Get the table
    var table = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children();
    $(table).each(function(){
        // Get the thead
        if($(this).is('thead')){
            var tds = $(this).children().children();
            var dateClicked = $(tds[caseNumber]).attr("data-date");
            alert(dateClicked);
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go- You will have to hack the calendar with a little bit of jquery to get this working. Its not great but all you need is this

Look at my fiddle also for working example

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/xCHLn/

Code

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
           var mousex = jsEvent.pageX;
           var mousey = jsEvent.pageY;
           $('td').each(function(index) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            if ((offset.left + $(this).outerWidth()) > mousex && offset.left < mousex && (offset.top + $(this).outerHeight()) > mousey && offset.top < mousey) {

                if ($(this).hasClass('fc-other-month')){
                    //Its a day on another month
                    //a high minus number means previous month
                    //a low minus number means next month
                    day = '-' + $(this).find('.fc-day-number').html();
                 $(this).css('color', 'red');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    //This is a day on the current month
                    day = $(this).find('.fc-day-number').html();
                         $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
                    }

             alert(day);
            }
```

Comment: ppumkin - that is a great start! However it has problems when the event start date is prior to the current month or the event end date goes beyond the current month. Based on your fiddle, I just changed the dates: http://jsfiddle.net/ha99b/

Comment: OK - it works now nicely- But to determine the previous and next month you must use some logic in your code. A previous number will come back as a minus number any high number x > 15 is next month a low number X < 15 is the previous month. This is an assumption that you can only see one month at a time. Otherwise a positive number means its clicked on the current month! $5 please =]

Answer (score 1):

"No - this goes to the START date of the event- He wants the DATE of the DAY where he clicked on the EVENT. Confusing hey? yea-- but very good idea he has. You answer is incorrect."

Sorry, but this goes to the Daydate

```
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar(
             {
              header: {
                     left: 'prev,next today',
                     center: 'title',
                     right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                     },
             editable: true,
             eventRender: function(event, element, view)
                  {
                  element.bind('click', function()
                         {
                         var day = ($.fullCalendar.formatDate( event.start, 'dd' ));
                         var month = ($.fullCalendar.formatDate( event.start, 'MM' ));
                         var year = ($.fullCalendar.formatDate( event.start, 'yyyy' ));
                          alert(year+'-'+month+'-'+day);
                         });
                   },
             events:[
                     {
                     "id":"1",
                     "title":"Garden",
                     "allDay":true,
                     "start":"1304770357"
                     }
                     ]
             });
```

Comment: NO! still shows start date - every click applies event.start so if event starts on 2010-01-14  then each alert shows me 14 even if i click on another day of the event

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/6wE8v/7/  look - there is your code. click on the event on day 11 - your alert show 10! incorrect Answer

Comment: you are right, it doesn´t run if the event is longer than a day :(

Comment: My question ... I can´t add comments :( please show ad fiddle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900156/no-callback-after-sqlite-request - I cant add new comments there, but I tried it in this http://jsfiddle.net/6wE8v/12/

Comment: not sure what the comments are about - you need more reputation most probably! Oh- i will check now- seems a bit strange- the fiddle i mean :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats great, now it was my mistake, the code-structure in the event.push must be: event.push({id:rs.field(0),title:rs.field(1)}); without quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better solution.

I solved the problem this way:

since the parameter *date* is a more or less javasxript object you can do this

```
 date.setDate(date.getDate() +1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the page coordinates returned with the jsEvent object along with a small plugin, and it works nicely for me.  The plugin is https://github.com/gilmoreorless/jquery-nearest and I use it like:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        var clickedDate = $.nearest({x: jsEvent.pageX, y: jsEvent.pageY}, '.fc-day').attr('data-date');
        //clickedDate will hold date from data-date attribute ex. YYYY-MM-DD
}
```

I wish it was just built in to the calEvent object - it sure would make things a lot easier

Comment: Your solution works great but it returns wrong date when we have many events on same date block and events are opening in a small popup.

Comment: How many events?  I added 9 and it still appears to return the correct date?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know, wether I understand correctly.

I realize it with this:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view)
    {
    element.bind('dblclick', function() 
           {
           var day = ($.fullCalendar.formatDate( event.start, 'dd' ));
           var month = ($.fullCalendar.formatDate( event.start, 'MM' ))-1;
           var year = ($.fullCalendar.formatDate( event.start, 'yyyy' ));
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView','agendaDay');
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', year, month,day);
           }
     }
```

Hope, this is, what you mean.
Watch out: The -1 in var month, because event.start - MM returns the normal month number, but the function gotoDate starts at 0

Comment: No - this goes to the START date of the event- He wants the DATE of the DAY where he clicked on the EVENT. Confusing hey? yea-- but very good idea he has. You answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and none of the solutions worked for me with fullcalendar 2.1.0. Here's what I ended up using:

```
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var posX = jsEvent.offsetX;
    $(jsEvent.currentTarget.offsetParent)
      .find("td[class~='fc-day-number']")
      .each(function(index) {
        if (posX >= this.offsetLeft - 3
            && posX <= (this.offsetLeft + this.offsetWidth - 3)) {
          var row = $(this).parents("div[class~='fc-row']").index(),
              col = index,
              date = view.cellToDate(row, col);
          alert('Clicked date = ' + date.toString());
          return false;
        }
      });
  },      
  events: [
    {
      title  : 'Long Event',
      start  : '2014-07-10',
      end    : '2014-09-25'
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Version 3 of fullcalendar this is the best solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /** initialize the calendar**/
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventClick: function(data, jsEvent) {
            var mouseX = jsEvent.pageX;
            var mouseY = jsEvent.pageY;
            var day = '';
            $('.fc-week').each(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                var top = Math.floor( offset.top );
                var height = $(this).outerHeight() + top;

                if( top <= mouseY && mouseY < height ) {
                    $(this).find('.fc-day-top').each(function() {
                        offset = $(this).offset();
                        var left = Math.floor( offset.left );
                        var width = $(this).outerWidth() + left;

                        if( left <= mouseX && mouseX < width ) {
                            day = $(this).attr('data-date');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For FC v4 and v5, Following methods will get the time using the cell user clicked on in timeGridWeek and timeGridDay views.
Co-ordinates are picked using the `jsEvent.currentTarget` element in the handleEventClick event as described in the diagram

[image]

The implementation is in Angular and does not uses jQuery. It is easily convertible to vanilla JS

*Fullcalendar v4:*

```
handleEventClick(e: EventClickArg) {
    const rect = e.jsEvent.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    const fcCellStartTime = (document.elementFromPoint(rect.left - window.pageXOffset, e.jsEvent.pageY - window.pageYOffset)
  .parentNode as HTMLTableRowElement).getAttribute('data-time');
    const selectedStartTime = moment(fcCellStartTime, 'HH:mm:ss');
}
```

*For Fullcalendar v5*

```
handleEventClick(clickInfo: EventClickArg) {
    const rect = (clickInfo.jsEvent.currentTarget as HTMLElement).getBoundingClientRect();
    let fcCellStartTime;
    const clickedElement = document.elementFromPoint(rect.left - window.pageXOffset, clickInfo.jsEvent.pageY - window.pageYOffset) as HTMLElement;
    // Cells with text will have data-time attribute in parent div
    if ((clickedElement.tagName) !== 'TD') {
        fcCellStartTime = (clickedElement.parentNode as HTMLDivElement).getAttribute("data-time");
    } else {// otherwise it is a blank hour cell and it will have data-time attrib
        fcCellStartTime = clickedElement.getAttribute("data-time");
    }
    const selectedStartTime = moment(fcCellStartTime, 'HH:mm:ss');
    console.log(selectedStartTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Implementation for `Fullcalendar 5`:

```
var mouseX = info.jsEvent.pageX;
var mouseY = info.jsEvent.pageY;
var day = '';

$('.fc-resourceTimelineWeek-view').each(function() {
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var top = Math.floor(offset.top);
  var height = $(this).outerHeight() + top;

  if (top <= mouseY && mouseY < height) {
    $(this).find('.fc-timeline-slot').each(function() {
      offset = $(this).offset();

      var left = Math.floor(offset.left);
      var width = $(this).outerWidth() + left;

      if (left <= mouseX && mouseX < width) {
        day = $(this).attr('data-date');
      }
    });
  }
});
```